# Handling of Duplicates in SAS & SQL

Tags: sql-server, sas

I have a SAS process which I am trying to replicate in SQL. There is a dataset of transactions in SAS which I had imported SQLServer via SSMS and which is the starting point.

There are 611K transactions in the dataset.

The process is very simple and straightforward. Remove duplicates and aggregate the data.

However, the final output doesnt reconcile between both the processes and I've been hitting my head on this.

One specific area which I had narrowed it down to is probably the handling of duplicates.

the way I do I am doing it in SQL to retain only the transaction with the oldest date and remove all other dupes is:

```
         select x2.*
         into #dupes
         --delete x2
         from #xl_Trans x2
         inner join (
                 select x1.id as id,min(x1.closedat) as min_closedat
                 from #xl_Trans x1
                inner join
                    (
                        select id,count(*) as CountOf
                        from #xl_Trans
                        group by id
                        having count(*) > 1
                    )x ON x1.id= x.id
        group by x1.id
        ) x3  ON x2.id = x3.id and x2.closedat <> x3.min_closedat


      corresponding code in SAS is:delete duplicates, keep the first occurrence

       proc sort data=temp1;by id;run;
       data temp1;
       set temp1;
       by id;
       if first.id;
       run;

 SQL process removed 1700 dupes whereas SAS identified about 2200+ dupes.
```

I know its hard to suggest without having the dataset, but I just want to know if there is anything in the SAS snippet that I am missing from in SQL which accounts for the discrepancy.

Comment: Do you have missing values for id or closedat?

Comment: Thanks @jms for responding. I checked that, but don't seem to have any missing values for these columns specifically.

Comment: I'd be curious if you have duplicates on the same date.  This is a situation that is _very_ hard to handle, fyi; SAS has a row-order concept that SQL does not, and so SAS is very happy to dedup even if it doesn't know what you're deciding is the rationale for order, while SQL really doesn't like to.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort is only by ID, not by a secondary date criteria. So the record being eliminated may not be the same as your SQL process. If it was similar your SORT would have another variable (date) on the BY statement.

```
 proc sort data=temp1;
 by id; -> NO DATE here;
 run;
```

If the value that you're aggregating on isn't the same across your different records you're going to have issues. And as mentioned, in your SQL if you have multiple dates as well as ID then you're going to have a difference in the number of records. SAS will always take only 1 record per ID, the SQL isn't guaranteed to do that.

Comment: Thank you @Reeza So, even in SQL, if I sort them by ID and retain only the first record, while I may get the counts, there is no guarantee that the same transaction/record is retain between both, correct? Different ways of sorting etc. Any thoughts on what I can do to get the exact results?

Comment: You can't AFAIK. In fact if you apply the same algorithms (above) on diff machines with diff processors it may handle them differently. Ran into this once in a project when we moved it from one site to another where Intel vs AMD processors. Sucks and worth noting as a logic fail in old process and moving on. But also need to handle the multiple issue in SQL. It's a fact of transitioning code - sometimes you find bugs.

Comment: Your sort shoud be done by id and date. Then, with the data set, fetch the first id.